# how to handle twilio error status when sending whatsapp message

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

when I try to send a whatsapp message to a mobile number that isn't registered on whatsapp, how do I know that it failed? because I want to send the message using regular SMS instead. but my code below doesn't give any different result between success and failed process:

```php
public function sendMessage($to, $msg, $params=[])
{
    $client = new Client($this->sid, $this->token);

    $from = $this->from_number; // my twilio number e.g. +1786xxxx

    if ( ! empty($params['via']) && $params['via'] == 'whatsapp') {
        $to = 'whatsapp:'.$to;
        $from = 'whatsapp:'.$from;
    }

    $options = [
        // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
        'from' => $from,
        // the body of the text message you'd like to send
        'body' => $msg,
    ];

    // Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
    $response = $client->messages->create(
        $to, 
        $options,
    );

    return $response;
}
// end public function sendMessage

public function do_send_msg()
{
    $to = '+628123456789';
    // this message already uses the same format as the approved message template
    $msg = "Your otp code for Login Process is 123456"; 
    $params = [
        'via' => 'whatsapp',
    ];
    $send = $this->twilio->sendMessage('+628123456789', $msg, $params);
    var_dump($send->status);
}
```

I wanted to make the code like this instead but this code is unable to differentiate the value of `$send->status` whether it's successful or failed:

```
public function do_send_msg()
{
    $to = '+628123456789';
    // this message already uses the same format as the approved message template
    $msg = "Your otp code for Login Process is 123456";
    $params = [
        'via' => 'whatsapp',
    ];
    $send = $this->sendMessage($to, $msg, $params);
    // if sending via whatsapp failed, try sending via regular SMS instead
    if ( ! $send->status ) {
        $params['via'] = 'SMS';
        $send = $this->sendMessage($to, $msg, $params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid Meta/WhatsApp doesn't expose this information at this point in time. Therefore, I'd recommend that you let the users choose whether they want to receive a WhatsApp message or a regular SMS.

Comment: oh? so we can't use Status Callback anymore? or has it never been possible to do this? because I did receive an email from twilio about Status Callback but the docs didn't elaborate on how to access the status itself.. if so then I might have no choice but to use this workaround..

Comment: You'll be able to see an error message in the log that says "(Error: 63003) Channel could not find To address" and yes, in theory you can use the status callback to "guess" that the number is not a valid WhatsApp number. But this is not an official workaround for this scenario.

Comment: yes, I saw the log in the twilio console. but is there any way to find that error code using PHP? one of the twilio technical support suggested to use a `try..catch` block. what do you think?

Comment: I'm afraid im not a PHP expert but I know that it's not possible in nodejs.